# How to configure php.in when uploading file with PHP

Tags: php

I use PHP to upload file to my server.I can't find my file in files folder.I suppose My code is right, but the file php.ini should be configured before uploading the file.Who can help me ?   Here is my html code:

```
<form action="upload_file.php?act=put&name=use_resource" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file">PUT：</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

My upload_file.php code is:

```
<?php
if ($_GET["act"] == "put")
{
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],  "files/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error that you got?

Comment: It shows Temp file:/data/www/tmp/phpwPGeJJ.But i can't find this file in /data/www/tmp/.Besides i can't find my file in files folder.

Comment: @AzisAbdulBachar , there is no error information.

Comment: Put this in the top of your php-script to turn on error report. ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
move_uploaded_file() returns a boolean value, which will be false if the temp file does not exist. If the file exists but can not be moved, an error will be raised.

Comment: Inside of the folder "files" should be the file you are uploading with it's original file name, NOT the temp name, according to your own code. Look in the "files" folder for the file with it's original file name, not the temp name. If it is not there, then something is preventing it from uploading, most likely a permission error. Make sure  that the "files" folder has write permissions for the world (assuming this is a linux/user server). Also, as you stated; make sure PHP allows file uploads. Some servers also require the "max file size" HTML input to be passed to the programming.

Comment: @EdwardB.You're right.I changed "files" to 777,it worked well.Thankyou

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is perfect and working, Did you give write access to 'files' folder?

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer

Comment: I cannot add my comment in my current badge.

Comment: @bala.s,you're right."files" folder  had not write permission.When it was changed to 777,it worked fine.